# Using innerHTML with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

I want to use something similar to the following to clear errors in a form upon a resubmission attempt:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#form-error-name, #form-error-email, #form-error-tel, #form-error-dob, #form-error-password, #form-error-goal").innerHTML= "";
```

...But the contents of the divs isn't cleared. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a collection of elements. `getElementById` returns just one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to loop through the results

```
    var errors = document.querySelectorAll(
               "#form-error-name, 
                #form-error-email, 
                #form-error-tel, 
                #form-error-dob, 
                #form-error-password, 
                #form-error-goal");

[].forEach.call(errors, function(error) {
  error.innerHTML = '';
});
```

`querySelectorAll` doesn't return an array, but a node list, which doesn't have a `forEach` method on its prototype.

The loop above is using the `forEach` method on the array object's prototype on the nodeList object.

Comment: Might be useful to explain that the result is a `NodeList.prototype` (rather than an `Array.prototype`, and without the array prototype methods) which is why you're using the `forEach` from array.

Comment: While this does work in modern browsers, there's no requirement for [*built–in*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.7) methods to work given a host object as *this* (e.g. IE 8 didn't like that), so a standard *for* loop over the NodeList is likely a better option (and probably faster to boot). ;-) Note that this particular case probably will work in IE8 since *forEach* must be shimmed and therefore isn't a built–in method.

Comment: @RobG thats a great point. Since browser support wasnt mentioned in the question and they where using querySelectorAll I didn't consider it, but in hindsight its an important factor in whether this is a good answer or not. I'd be interested in seeing the perf diff of forEach and for(var i = 0; etc loop

Comment: It is worth noting that only IE 11 does not support forEach on NodeList. So, if you are not targeting obsolete browsers, you can do away with the shenanigans and simply use forEach on NodeList returned from document.querySelectorAll.

Answer (score 12):

The question wants `.innerHTML`, but that's not valid on `input`; you actually want `.value`.  The appropriate modern answer would be

```
[... document.querySelectorAll('input')]
  .map(i => i.value = '');
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("#form-error-name, #form-error-email, #form-error-tel");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].innerHTML = "";
}
```

See, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to call forEach directly on the results of `querySelectorAll`, which returns NodeList resutls:

```js
query_selector = "#form-error-name, #form-error-email, #form-error-tel, #form-error-dob, #form-error-password, #form-error-goal"
document.querySelectorAll(query_selector).forEach(node => node.innerHTML = "")
```