# How to highlight "headlines" of any webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a Chrome Extension that automatically highlights the top headlines of the webpage.
I have this code that uses the id or element of HTML.
The problem I encounter is different sites use different elements like h1 h2 etc, where sometimes it will not work.

Simple question: How can I highlight any webpage headlines (Only Headlines)

```js
function highlight(text) {
  var inputText = document.getElementById("title");
  var innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML = text
  var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
  if (index >= 0) {
    innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0, index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + innerHTML.substring(index, index + text.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
    inputText.innerHTML = innerHTML;
  }
}
highlight("Title");
```

```css
.highlight {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Heading</h1>
```

Comment: it the problem is the h tag number just loop them

Comment: Note that the code shown changes the text of the heading to be the text passed to the `highlight` function (the text was originally "Heading" and the code changed it to "Title"). This may be what you want to happen, be I would be surprised if an extension changed all of the headers on my websites to "Title".

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes it highlights all the text

Comment: It changes all of the text, then highlights it.

Comment: @saikishore, I have corrected the code. It should work now. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

just use `document.getElementsByTagName("h[NUM]");`

```
function highlight(text) {
    for(var i=1;i<=6;i++){ //since there is h1-h6 headers
    var inputTexts = document.getElementsByTagName("h"+i);
    for(var j=0;i<inputTexts.length;j++){
        var innerHTML = inputTexts[j].innerHTML=text
        var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
        if (index >= 0) {
            innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0,index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + 
            innerHTML.substring(index,index+text.length) + "</span>" + 
            innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
            inputTexts[j].innerHTML = innerHTML;
         }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at this line =>for(int i=1;i<=6;i++){

Comment: I got confused suppose  to be var not int

Comment: OK, the code runs successfully but didn't get any result. Should I add any CSS to the code or just the above code is enough? and has <h1> tag.

Comment: you should create highlight css class

Comment: but i suppose that sergey's answer is better

Comment: @ATP, thanks, bro. i really appreciate that. your solution is also good, but it needs to be corrected a little.

Answer (score 0):

This can be made even easier using `querySelectorAll`. Like this:

```
var inputText = document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');
```

Thus, the code will determine which specific `h` tag is registered in the header.

Also add indexing. Like this:

```
inputText[i];
```

Now try to manually change tags (from `h1` ... `h6`) in the code `HTML` and run the code.

```js
function highlight(text) {
var inputText = document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');

  for( var i = 0; i < inputText.length; i++ ) {
     inputText[i].classList.add('highlight');
  }
}
    
highlight("Title");
```

```css
.highlight {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<h3>Title</h3>
```

Comment: `inputText.innerHTML` will throw an error, since `inputText` is a `NodeList`, and that doesn't have an `innerHTML` property.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, i made a reproducible example. Check it out. And look it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983388/using-innerhtml-with-queryselectorall

Comment: Ah, my bad, it just adds the `innerHTML` property to the `inputText` object. It doesn't actually set anything meaningful in the DOM. You could leave out that part and just do `var innerHTML = text` and it would behave the same. And, since `innerHTML === text`, `index` is always 0, so the rest of the code is just wrapping the text with the span.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined

inputText[index].innerHTML = innerHTML;   <===the error appears here!

Comment: It's working for <table> tag but not for heading tags! really weird.

https://pasteboard.co/JEiefcS.png

Comment: This is really strange, since the reference exclusively to tags `h` - `querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6')`.

Comment: Tell me, do you still use the `inputText` variable somewhere in your code? this is most likely due to this variable.

Comment: No, I didn't use it anywhere. It doesn't work on the normal webpage and works only on the GitHub page. And clearly showed the script has been injected

Comment: @saikishore, Hello. Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Yes, I did. :)

Comment: @saikishore, How did you manage to solve the problem, if not a secret?

Comment: I have matched the tab.title, and used the h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 and matched and displayed the line, mean while it have some bugs too.